# angular 6 scss error

Tags: angular, sass

I'm use angular 6.0.1 and when i create a style class, it's give me error like in screen short and you can also see my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "6.1.0",
"@angular/cdk": "6.4.1",
"@angular/common": "6.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "6.1.0",
"@angular/core": "6.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "6.1.0",
"@angular/http": "6.1.0",
"@angular/material": "6.4.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.0",
"@angular/router": "6.1.0",
"angular2-notifications": "^1.0.2",
"bootstrap": "3.3.7",
"core-js": "2.5.4",
"rxjs": "6.0.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.26"
```

and i getting error like 
[image]

and my code look like

```
.mat-sidenav-container
   position: fixed
   height: 100%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be like ,

```
.mat-sidenav-container
{
   position: fixed;
   height: 100%;
}
```

you need `{}` around your css class you are defining.

Comment: You forgot about `semicolons` at the end of every rule